# Re-assigning IDs in a non-IDENTITY type field in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008r2-express

***WARNING: This tale of woe contains examples of code smells and poor design decisions, and technical debt.***

If you are conversant with SOLID principles, practice TDD and unit test your work, ***DO NOT READ ON***. Unless you want a good giggle at someone's misfortune and gloat in your own awesomeness knowing that you would never leave behind such a monumental pile of crap for your successors.

So, if you're sitting comfortably then I'll begin.

In this app that I have inherited and been supporting and bug fixing for the last 7 months I have been left with a DOOZY of a balls up by a developer that left 6 and a half months ago. Yes, 2 weeks after I started.

Anyway. In this app we have `clients`, `employees` and `visits` tables.

There is also a table called `AppNewRef` (or something similar) that ... wait for it ... contains the next record ID to use for each of the other tables. So, may contain data such as :-

```
TypeID    Description     NextRef
   1      Employees       804
   2      Clients         1708
   3      Visits          56783
```

When the application creates new rows for `Employees`, it looks in the `AppNewRef` table, gets the value, uses that value for the ID, and then updates the `NextRef` column. Same thing for `Clients`, and `Visits` and all the other tables whose `NextID` to use is stored in here.

Yes, I know, no auto-numbering `IDENTITY` columns on this database. All under the excuse of "when it was an Access app". These ID's are held in the (VB6) code as longs. So, up to 2 billion 147 million records possible. OK, that seems to work fairly well. (apart from the fact that the app is updating and taking care of locking / updating, etc., and not the database)

So, our users are quite happily creating `Employees`, `Clients`, `Visits` etc. The `Visits ID` is steady increasing a few dozen at a time. Then the problems happen. Our clients are causing database corruptions while creating batches of visits because the server is beavering away nicely, and the app becomes unresponsive. So they kill the app using task manager instead of being patient and waiting. Granted the app does seem to lock up.

Roll on to earlier this year and developer Tim (real name. No protecting the guilty here) starts to modify the code to do the batch updates in stages, so that the UI remains 'responsive'. Then April comes along, and he's working his notice (you can picture the scene now, can't you ?) and he's beavering away to finish the updates.

End of April, and beginning of May we update some of our clients. Over the next few months we update more and more of them.

Unseen by Tim (real name, remember) and me (who started two weeks before Tim left) and the other new developer that started a week after, the ID's in the visit table start to take huge leaps upwards. By huge, I mean 10000, 20000, 30000 at a time. Sometimes a few hundred thousand.

Here's a graph that illustrates the rapid increase in IDs used.

[image: Take a look at his graph]

Roll on November. Customer phones Tech Support and reports that he's getting an error. I look at the error message and ask for the database so I can debug the code. I find that the value is too large for a long. I do some queries, pull the information, drop it into Excel and graph it.

I don't think making the code handle anything longer than a long for the ID's is the right approach, as this app passes that ID into other DLL's and OCX's and breaking the interface on those just seems like a whole world of hurt that I don't want to encounter right now.

One potential idea that I'm investigating is try to modify the ID's so that I can get them down to a lower level. Essentially filling the gaps. Using the `ROW_NUMBER` function

What I'm thinking of doing is adding a new column to each of the tables that have a Foreign Key reference to these Visit ID's *(not a proper foreign key mind, those constraints don't exist in this database).* This new column could store the old (current) value of the Visit ID (oh, just to confuse things; on some tables it's called `EventID`, and on some it's called `VisitID`).

Then, for each of the other tables that refer to that `VisitID`, update to the new value.

Ideas ? Suggestions ? Snippets of T-SQL to help all gratefully received.

Comment: Quick question. Is it supposed to jump 100' numbers at a time? If not, is this fixed?

Comment: So, just that I understand this right: The `AppNewRef` table is consulted when a new ID for a data table is needed, then the number in it is incremented. Due to unfortunate circumstances the `NextRef` values leap up, leaving huge gaps of unused IDs while overflowing the data type at some point. Correct?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Are these IDs used as foreign keys by other tables? Are you able to set those foreign keys as `ON UPDATE CASCADE`? Is there a chance that those IDs are recorded anywhere else what such a cascaded update won't cover you? Do you have a test/develop environment where you can try these changes? Are you able to modify the schema to use an Identity Column *(with its implications on INSERT syntax, etc)*? Are you in a position to refactor the code to store queries as StoredProcedures in the DB and not the application? What is the maximum scope of the 'fix' suggestions?

Comment: Asken - no, it's supposed to increment 1 (or by however many visit records get created), and no, it's not fixed yet. I need to get the ID's down so that the customer can get using the app again.

Comment: Tomalak - Yes that's it.

Comment: Dems - SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. They are used as Foreign Key-type relationships to other tables, but the Foreign Key relationships are not defined in the database. Yes, I have a test/dev environment I can try the changes on (my machine). I could modify the schema. One thing about the app is that former developers created a mechanism for updating the DB schema when the app runs against that database. (and stops old versions of the app working with newer database schemas).

Comment: Dems - I want to modify the schema to use an IDENTITY column, and use sprocs to insert the records, but can't make those kind of changes at present.

Answer (score 2):

**Option one:**

Explicitly constrain all of your foreign key relationships, and set them to be `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

This will mean that whenever you change the ID, the foreign keys will automatically be updated.

Then you just run something like this...

```
WITH
  resequenced AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS newID,
    *
  FROM
    yourTable
)
UPDATE
  resequenced
SET
  id = newID
```

I haven't done this in ***ages***, so I forget if it causes problems mid-update by having two records with the same id value.  If it does, you could do somethign like this first...

```
UPDATE yourTable SET id = -id
```

**Option two:**

Ensure that ***none*** of your foreign key relationships are explicitly defined.  If they are, note them donw and remove them.

Then do something like...

```
CREATE TABLE temp AS
  newID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
  oldID INT
)

INSERT INTO temp (oldID) SELECT id FROM yourTable

/* Do this once for the table you are re-identifiering              */
/* Repeat this for all fact tables holding that ID as a foreign key */
UPDATE
  factTable
SET
  foreignID = temp.newID
FROM
  temp
WHERE
  foreignID = temp.oldID
```

Then re-apply any existing foreign key relationships.

This is a pretty scary option.  If you forget to update a table, you just borked your data.  But, you ***can*** give that `temp` table a much nicer name and KEEP it.

Good luck.  And may the lord have mercy on your soul.  And Tim's if you ever meet him in a dark alley.

Comment: +1 I like option one. Since the client application seems to cause the gaps, they are likely to occur again - so unless the application is fixed this probably would have to become part of a nightly database maintenance routine.

Comment: @Tomalak - Unless explicitly creating foreign key constraints breaks some other logic in the application.  If it's being designed to have foreign relationships, but doesn't constrain them, there is no actual guarantee that all the relationships will conform to the constraint *(and maybe some other unexpect side-effects)*.

Comment: +1, and I don't think there should be anything scary about atomic, or else "atomicised" (if there is such a word), operations.

Comment: @AndriyM - Each individual update should be fine.  Having to do them this way because you haven't enforced constraints, and so may not be aware of every key that needs updating, that's scary ;)

Comment: Yes, I get it now, thanks. However, if the data integrity is initially enforced, I think you should be fine. I can imagine the following scenario. First, you try modifying only the PK IDs. If there's a foreign key in effect, you'll apparently run into an error. The message will tell you which FK was violated. You amend your query (to disable the constraint, "compress" the IDs, update the FKs, enable the constraint back), run it, and if there's another foreign key not accounted for, it'll be violated too. And so you amend the query once more and try it again, and so on until there's no error.

Comment: (It is implied that you do everything in a transaction and you roll it back immediately once there's an error.)

Answer (score 1):

I would create a numbers table that has just a sequence from 1 to whatever max with an increment of 1 is for long and then change the logic of getting the maxid for visitid and maybe the others doing a right join between the numbers and the visits table. and then you can just look for te min of that number

```
select min(number) from visits right join numbers on visits.id = numbers.number
```

That way you get all the gaps filled in without having to change any of the other tables.

but I would just redo the whole database.